# Plane and open unit disc are homeomorphic. Plane is closed, but disc is open. What's wrong here?

Tags: general-topology

We know that the (complex) plane and open unit disc are homeomorphic. The plane, being the entire space is closed, but the disc is open. What am I messing up with? Should I consider the open unit disc as its own topological space hence clopen, rather than as a open subset of the plane?

Comment: The open unit disc is not closed in the plane, but it is closed in the open unit disc. Let $h: \; {\text {plane}} \rightarrow {\text {open disc}}$ be a homeomorphism. In the domain, "plane" is closed. In the co-domain , "open disc" is closed. Given a homeomorphism $h:X \rightarrow Y$ and $B \subseteq Y,$ the notions of "open" and "closed" for $B$ are for $B$ in $Y.$ Note that while it might happen that the **set** $B$ is also a **subset** of $X$ (the case you're dealing with), in general $B$ as a set might be entirely disjoint from $X.$ (@Anne Bauval's comment is probably more to the point.)

Answer (score 1):

Being closed or open as a subspace of some larger topological space is not a ["topological property", i.e. (by definition) is not invariant under homeomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_property), contrarily to, for instance, being compact or connected, which is "intrinsic" (does not depend on any larger space). You already noted that the open disc is closed in itself. Note also that the complex plane can also be considered as not closed, when identified to a subspace of [the sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere).

Comment: I don't know why you got a downvote for this (converted from your earlier, now deleted, comment), but maybe what I said is actually more to the point, contrary to what I said in my comment? That is, in my comment, I might have been (roughly speaking) wrong about being wrong. I'm a bit busy with something else now, however, to give much thought to this.

Comment: Thank you. I can see no sensible reason either. It was the agreement in your previous comment which pushed me to convert my comment into an answer.

Comment: @coudy "Topological property" has a precise definition, which I already recalled, and which excluded "being open". I just added a link. Since the answer has been edited, you can now change your vote if you want.

Comment: Note that being open in ${\bf R}^2$ is invariant by homeomorphism. This is the content of the  invariance of domain theorem.

Comment: Thank you coudy! (I did not quote that because I don't think it was really the subject.)

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, you correctly answered your own question. When we talk about sets being homeomorphic, we don’t care what else there is outside the sets; it’s a statement about the internal structure of the sets, which is, as you say, their structure as (sub)spaces.